# Trying to access the property of an embedded type of a model

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I cannot display the property of an embedded type.
How can I access the property of an embedded type of a model (e.g. **CustomerOrderItem.Meal.Name**) in a razor page?

Razor Page:

```
@page
@model RazorPages.Pages.BasketOrder.IndexModel
@{

}
@if (Model.ShowMessage)
{
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="alert alert-info">@Model.Message</div>
}
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerOrderItems[0].Meal.Name)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var m in Model.CustomerOrderItems)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@m.Meal.Name</td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

In 'Code behind' file, the **OnGetAsync** - Method gets the **CustomerOrderItems**.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _db;

    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public IList<CustomerOrderItem> CustomerOrderItems { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool ShowMessage => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message);

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _db = db;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        CustomerOrderItems = await _db.CustomerOrderItems.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

The Model classes, **CustomOrderItem** has a reference to  a **Meal**.

```
public class CustomerOrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public CustomerOrder CustomerOrder { get; set; }
    public Meal Meal { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Extra> Extras { get; set; }
}

public class Meal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What version EF are you using?

Comment: I use EF Core 2.

Comment: Yeah you can use eagar loading,explict loading and Projected Queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meal is a concreate object inside of customer. EFcore 2 doesn't come with lazy loading but its not a huge problem.

You can use eagar loading :

```
//With eagerloading DbSet 
  //has method called include. Dont abuse eagerloading slows down db

  CustomerOrderItems = await _db.CustomerOrderItems
.Include(x => x.Meals).ToListAsync();

//also initialize that Collection in your constructor if you want to use it
```